# Authenticating (claims) to Sharepoint/Office356 through PHP and SOAP

Tags: php, sharepoint, authentication, soap, office365

I am trying to make SOAP requests to Sharepoint lists (via 'http://url.co.uk/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL) using PHP5's standard SOAP lib that require authentication. I had it working fine using NTLM authentication (which was a pain but worked in the end) but now the remit of the project is to authenticate through CLAIMS so that it will work for either a Sharepoint install or an office365 instance.

I realised from the outset that a standard SOAP authentication would not work...but I tried it anyway! Unsurprisingly, I received an error back "List Fault code: HTTPList Fault string: Forbidden".

Is it possible to Authenticate through CLAIMS by a Pure PHP/SOAP based solution and if so what is the best way of achieving this? I have read varying articles on Claims auth for sharepoint with varying solutions using Apache tricks etc to authenticate. The project I am working on requires this to be a pure PHP solution.

It may be worth pointing out that I am not a MS developer and have limited knowledge on CLAIMS authentication (which probably doesn't help!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more info (PHP-specific) that might be of help as well. I haven't tried it myself yet so can't say if it actually works:

http://macfoo.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/how-to-log-into-office365-or-sharepoint-online-using-php/

http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/

http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

[phpSPO - SharePoint client for PHP](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) library  allows you to performs CRUD operations on SharePoint list data using an REST/OData based API for SharePoint Online.

The current version supports SharePoint Online using claims based authentication.

### Examples

How to perform authentication in SharePoint Online (SPO):

```
try {
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);
    echo 'You have been authenticated successfully\n';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Authentication failed: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any examples for PHP - these explain the process and give an implementation in C# that it should be possible to rewrite in PHP.

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx