# How to authenticate with SharePoint Online for a PHP app?

Tags: php, sharepoint, authentication, single-sign-on, office365

We have our PHP application that requires authentication, and for our clients that run SharePoint we'd like to offer some kind of SSO service, so that the users can use their SharePoint credentials (we did something similar with Google Apps, CAS, ...)

Note: Obviously, our app is not hosted on the same domain/premices as SharePoint

I can't find the litterature about it, so any pointer would be welcome !

NB: we'd like to implement a proper tier authentification mechanism, so that the user can log into our app directly by typing the URL, and choose to login using SharePoint, exactly like you'd do with OAuth and the like...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate - but very close - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973397/authenticating-claims-to-sharepoint-office356-through-php-and-soap

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: If they use Sharepoint can it be assumed they use Active Directory for authentication? Rather than SSO you could auth through LDAP. The user/password would be the same atleast :) http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePoint Online (SPO) supports  *claims based authentication*.

The below picture demonstrates how authentication is performed in SPO:

[image]

According to [this post](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/) the authentication process consists of the following steps:

> Steps:
>
> 1. Send SAML Request to STS
> 2. Receive SAML Response
> 3. Send the Security Token to SharePoint Online
> 4. Receive the authentication cookies
> 5. Send requests including authentication cookies

---

[phpSPO - SharePoint client for PHP](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) supports SPO authentication.

> The library provides a SharePoint Online (SPO) client for PHP
> applications. It allows you to performs CRUD operations on SharePoint
> data using an SharePoint 2013 REST/OData based API.

### Examples

How to perform authentication in SharePoint Online (SPO):

```
try {
    $client = new SPOClient($url);
    $client->signIn($username,$password);
    echo 'You have authenticated successfully\n';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Authentication failed: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

The following examples demonstrates how to perform  CRUD operations on SharePoint list data:

```
<?php
 
require_once 'SPOClient.php';
 
$username = 'username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com';
$password = 'password';
$url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/";
 
$client = new SPOClient($url);
$client->signIn($username,$password);
 
//Get Tasks list
$listTitle = 'Tasks';
$list = $client->getList($listTitle);
    
//Create a Task item
$itemProperties = array('Title' => 'Order Approval', 'Body' => 'Order approval task');
$taskItem = $list->addItem($itemProperties);
print "Task '{$taskItem->Title}' has been created succesfully.\r\n";
 
$itemId = $taskItem->Id;
//Update a Task item
$itemProperties = array('PercentComplete' => 1);
$list->updateItem($itemId,$itemProperties);
 
//Delete a Task item
$list->deleteItem($itemId);
 
?>
```

### References

[SharePoint Online client for PHP](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/31/sharepoint-online-client-php/)

Comment: Thanks Vadim, we finaly do that using SimpleSAML, but the idea is the same indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need help on this - Sharepoint is usually set to sync up with Active directory (AD/LDAP). So really if you have users that use sharepoint AND are being internally authenticated in their company via their Active directory login, then what you may want to look at is authenticating your app against LDAP (and use the email address or domain id as the username)

Here is some more info on that:
[Authenticating in PHP using LDAP through Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171519/authenticating-in-php-using-ldap-through-active-directory)

Comment: Thanks, although usualy our clients don't open their LDAP account outside their network. Most often the use SAML instead.